# Lack of Rotational Invariance in Relativistic Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, scattering, invariants

In ['Lectures of Sidney Coleman on Quantum Field Theory'](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/9371#t=aboutBook) the first paragraph of the first chapter briefly discusses the lack of rotational invariance in relativistic quantum mechanics. I will quote Coleman,

> 'In non-relativistic quantum mechanics, rotational invariance
> simplifies scattering problems. Why does adding in special relativity,
> to include Lorentz invariance, complicate quantum mechanics?'

While I can grasp that the argument relates to the relativistic Hamiltonian, but can someone explicitly show me with the suitable mathematical arguments what Coleman is trying to convey here?

Comment: Coleman does not claim that in relativistic QM there is a *lack* of rotational invariance. In fact, Lorentz invariance includes rotational invariance and is therefore a stricter requirement. That's all that he is trying to convey here.

Comment: So, Kurt G what I understand is that relativistic quantum mechanics also has rotational invariance (of, course - else the world will stop going around), but the Physics is 'messier'?

Comment: I recommend to study a bit the failed attempts to combine relativity with the Schrödinger equation. Also, Peskin & Schroeder have a nice section in their QFT book where they explain why only relativistic QFT is compatible with causality. If someone finds that 'messier' is any ones own opinion.

Comment: I read the Peskin & Schroeder part about the issues KG equation has with causality (and how events tend to happen outside the light-cone). However, as I have said - the first paragraph of Coleman (I also watched the video lecture at youtube) left me puzzled. I am not entirely sure if Coleman deals with this part (rotational invariance and QM/QFT) later in his book.

Comment: Cannot comment what Coleman deals with later in the book. Don't even have that. Be patient, keep reading, solve exercises and press on. If we were to get headaches by every sentence we get puzzled with in those book we would never make any progress.

Comment: How did you know that I am self-studying QFT - curiosity got the better of me!? :-D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138765/discussion-between-arkapravo-and-kurt-g).